# Add dash in text field in Power Bi / Powerquery

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a column in PowerBi namend X-rates. The value in the column is for example X00360. I want to change that value to X-00360. So after the X i need "-" sign.

In Excel i used `iferror(CONCATENATE(left(O2;1));"-";right(O2;lenght(O2)-1));"")`
but how to do this in powerquery?

```
X-rates (current) X-ratesNew (expected)
 X00360            X-00360
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Add a new column and type in

```
Text.Start([#"X-rates (current) "],1) & "-" & Text.Middle([#"X-rates (current) "], 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In powerquery, add column, custom column with formula

```
= Text.ReplaceRange([#"X-rates"], 0, 1, Text.Start([#"X-rates"],1)&"-")
```